# Can my network admin see my traffic over a Flask app?

Tags: http, wireshark

So I've got a Flask app that connects to the internet to send/receive data. It does so by connecting to a website's API (which has HTTPS). So I'm quite sure the Flask app is HTTP. I connect as `127.0.0.1:7200` and I can't connect as `https://127.0.0.1:7200`.

Does that mean network admin eg. work WiFi or university WiFi, can see everything I'm sending? I sniffed around on Wireshark and netstat with my PID but I can't seem to find the packets coming from the app.

I looked around online and saw that network admins can see HTTP data easily. I'm mainly concerned if they can see the exact data I'm sending, not if they can see what websites/IPs I'm connecting to/for how long. Personal device, Windows 11 Home, wireless connection to work/school internet.

If my Flask app is HTTP but the API I'm sending and receiving to is HTTPS, can they see what data I'm sending?

**EDIT APRIL 2024:** A bit late but for anyone who finds this in the future: I found the packets coming from the app- if you are connecting to an external HTTPS source, your traffic is secured under TLS (at least mine was for the external source I was using).

Comment: They potentially could, but in practical reality won’t waste time and energy to do so. Unless, of course, your traffic numbers are high enough or interfere enough with network services to make your traffic a concern.

Comment: They can tell your using Flask but unless they are using a M2TM certificate they can do deep packet inspection on the traffic on HTTPS traffic. Likewise, HTTP is NOT encrypted and transmitted as plain text. If you are concerned, **do not use it**, while connected to their network. I mentioned HTTPS traffic first on purpose.

Comment: The situation is unclear, sorry. You are connecting to the app on your local PC. That's "invisible". But what does the app do?

Comment: It connects to Mistral, an LLM (basically like ChatGPT's API), and I'm basically just using the LLM in a Flask app. My main concern is that the network admin can see the data going to/back from Mistral eg. my chat history. Sorry for not making that clear in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to a web app that’s hosted locally on your PC using `localhost`, `127.x.x.x` or `::1`, the resulting network traffic never leaves the computer. Outside parties cannot see, detect or intercept it.

If the app is not listening on either of those addresses but instead on all addresses (`0.0.0.0`/`::`), the web app might be accessible from the outside and may leak data that way.

As long as the app itself is connecting to remote resources using encrypted protocols, this data, too, is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your IT admin (or anyone else for that matter) can use a Packet Sniffer to see HTTP data streams. CommView and Wireshark both work. I use CommView.

Some software can reconstruct data streams. It is often not cheap or easy to reconstruct streams.  It depends on the viewer if the effort is worth it.

See for example:   [See data streams](https://medium.com/a-bit-off/rebuilding-network-flows-in-gol-d89cfa0884ae)

Comment: Alright, thanks. So if my endpoint is HTTPS, would that encrypt my receiving traffic, or not because I'm still on HTTP?

Comment: The HTTP streams can be read in a packet sniffer and then decoded with other software. That is partly why almost everything is HTTPS now.

Comment: Alright, thanks, so both sending and receiving are HTTP.